# How to replay not only last items from sequence, but last items within each group from sequence?

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

I have a hot observable that emits `Pair<key,value>`. I need that every new subscriber receive last `value` for each `key` and all subsequent items.

Example. Observable emits this sequence:

```
Time point 0.
Pair<0,1>
Pair<0,2>
Pair<1,0>
Pair<1,1>
Time point 1. Subscriber A subscribes
Pair<0,3>
Pair<1,2>
Time point 2. Subscriber B subscribes
Pair<2,1>
```

Subscriber A should see:

```
Pair<0,2>
Pair<1,1>
Pair<0,3>
Pair<1,2>
Pair<2,1>
```

Subscriber B should see:

```
Pair<0,3>
Pair<1,2>
Pair<2,1>
```

Initially I was thinking about `ReplaySubject` but I don't want to hold in memory all items. I can't apply `ReplaySubject` with `capacity` because I need to set a capacity not for entire sequence, but for each group.

Only solution that I see is to transform `Observable<Pair<key,value>>` to `Observable<Observable<Pair<key,value>>>` like this:

```
mConnectableObservable = InitialHotObservable //emits items Pair<key,value>
                    .groupBy(pair -> pair.first)
                    .map(groupedObservable -> {
                        Subject<Pair<Integer, Integer>, Pair<Integer, Integer>> subject = BehaviorSubject.create();
                        groupedObservable.subscribe(subject::onNext);
                        return subject.asObservable();
                    })
                    .replay();
mConnectableObservable.connect();
```

Subscription to this observable will looks like this:

```
mCompositeSubcription = new CompositeSubscription();
mTestSubscription = mCountDownPresenter.start2()
        .subscribe(pairObservable ->
                        mCompositeSubcription.add(
                                pairObservable
                                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                        .subscribe(pair -> doSomething(pair))
                        )
        );
```

**Questions**

1. Did I choose correct approach? Could you point me to simpler solution?
2. Am I right that I should call `mTestSubscription.unSubscribe()` and `mCompositeSubcription.unSubscribe`?
3. When my `InitialHotObservable` completes, should I somehow deal with `BehaviorSubject's`

**Update**

Instead of using `BehaviorSubject` I can use `replay`

```
mConnectableObservable = InitialHotObservable //emits items Pair<key,value>
                    .groupBy(pair -> pair.first)
                    .map(groupedObservable -> {
                        ConnectableObservable<Pair<Integer,Integer>> observable = groupedObservable.asObservable().replay(1);
                        observable.connect();
                        return observable.asObservable();
                    })
                    .replay();
mConnectableObservable.connect();
```

In this case I don't know should explicitly call `unsibcribe` on `observable.connect();` and `mConnectableObservable.connect();` subscriptions.

Comment: Do your solutions work now (not considering correctness of cleanup and resetting replays etc)?

Comment: @DaveMoten It works (at least the main scenario). At the moment, I do some experiments and tests with it.